# Did "Mrs" originally imply possession?

Tags: meaning, etymology, possessives

Was *Mrs* ever intended to mean *Mr's*, as in *mister's* to indicate possession?  I started thinking about this when someone brought a breakdown of the word *history* (*his-story*) to my attention.  It obviously would be very sexist but not surprising.

Comment: "History" is not really his + story (although you can break it down that way). In French, it is *histoire* even though *his* is not the male possessive. You might be interested in a better etymology [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=history)

Comment: @simchona - Bah. You're ruining a perfectly good expression of outrage with your pesky *facts*.

Comment: @simchona: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herstory

Comment: @Cesar I'm aware of the feminist reinterpretation of historiography. I brought up the French because the OP sounded like he thought "his story" was the actual breakdown of the word.

Comment: Hi @Matthew. I hope you don't think it rude, but there is an answer ripe for the accepting. Can you come and give it a look over and see if it meets your needs? If it doesn't, let us know how we can make it better.

Comment: @simchona: Fair enough. One never knows... :-)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Mrs* is the written form of *missus*. The [EtymOnline entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=missus) writes that *missus* is a:

> corruption of mistress; as oral form of Mrs., from 1790; the missus “the wife” attested by 1833.

Tracing back further to the [entry for mistress](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mistress) uncovers:

> early 14c., "female teacher, governess," from O.Fr. maistresse, fem. of maistre "master" (see master). Sense of "a woman who employs others or has authority over servants" is from early 15c. Sense of "kept woman of a married man" is from early 15c.

Where did *mister* come from? It's a corruption of [master](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=master) :

> O.E. mægester "one having control or authority," from L. magister "chief, head, director, teacher" (cf. O.Fr. maistre, Fr. maître, It. maestro, Ger. Meister), influenced in M.E. by O.Fr. maistre, from L. magister, contrastive adj. from magis (adv.) "more," itself a comp. of magnus "great."

So *mister* and *missus* derive from the male and female forms of *maistre*--they share a root. *Mrs* is not derived from a possessive form of *Mr*.

Comment: An interesting video on the subject: [hotforwords Mr. and Mrs.](http://www.hotforwords.com/2008/03/17/mr-mrs/)

Comment: Interestingly, the Dutch word _Meester_ is used to address a primary school teacher, and it's the formal title of a lawyer (abbreviated as mr.). In addition, engine drivers are also called  _Meester_ and it is sometimes used in the bible to address Jesus. However, it is never used in the same way as the English _Mister_, for which the Dutch use _Meneer_, which derives from _Mijn heer_ (my Lord) (compare with the German _Mein Herr_). There is a female form of _Meester_, namely _Meesteres_,  but nowadays it is almost exclusively used to denote a dominant woman in the context of SM.

Comment: *Mr* is also the abbreviation for Master, as in 'Master of Arts' (probably the origin of the more generic form). In this sense, the feminine is *Mra*, from Latin *magistra*. I have seen this used once in my life: the equivalent for PhDs, *Drx*,  is more common (perhaps three or four times).